# Using pefile to get the application name

Tags: python

Simply put: is there any way to use the `pefile` module in order to get the an executable's name?

What I mean by the name is what we see here as the *Description*:
[image: Illustration]

Also, if not possible with PEFile, is it possible with something else? (if possible without `pywin32` to make it as universal as possible).

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with PEFile that easily. I advise you use `pywin32` (which only works under Windows, but that's already something).

You can use that: (stolen from another answer)

```
def getFileProperties(fname):
    """
    Reads all properties of the given file return them as a dictionary.
    """
    propNames = ('Comments', 'InternalName', 'ProductName',
                'CompanyName', 'LegalCopyright', 'ProductVersion',
                'FileDescription', 'LegalTrademarks', 'PrivateBuild',
                'FileVersion', 'OriginalFilename', 'SpecialBuild')

    props = {'FixedFileInfo': None, 'StringFileInfo': None, 'FileVersion': None}

    try:
        # backslash as parm returns dictionary of numeric info corresponding to VS_FIXEDFILEINFO struc
        fixedInfo = win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(fname, '\\')
        props['FixedFileInfo'] = fixedInfo
        props['FileVersion'] = "%d.%d.%d.%d" % (fixedInfo['FileVersionMS'] / 65536,
                                                fixedInfo['FileVersionMS'] % 65536, 
                                                fixedInfo['FileVersionLS'] / 65536,
                                                fixedInfo['FileVersionLS'] % 65536)

        # \VarFileInfo\Translation returns list of available (language, codepage)
        # pairs that can be used to retreive string info. We are using only the first pair.
        lang, codepage = win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(fname, '\\VarFileInfo\\Translation')[0]

        # any other must be of the form \StringfileInfo\%04X%04X\parm_name, middle
        # two are language/codepage pair returned from above

        strInfo = {}
        for propName in propNames:
            strInfoPath = u'\\StringFileInfo\\%04X%04X\\%s' % (lang, codepage, propName)
            ## print str_info
            strInfo[propName] = win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(fname, strInfoPath)

        props['StringFileInfo'] = strInfo
    except:
        pass

    return props
```